# Mimicking third party API

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, stub

What is the best way to mimic third party API? I am using third party API which has down time on test environment. Because of it our QA team gets idle, I want to mimic the API using there responses logged with us so QA team can continue testing while downtime.

Comment: This question is unclear and too broad. Are you trying to mock them for testing? Use any mocking solution from google ([Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) for ex.). If you trying to recreate (reverse engineering) and replace it - create some sort-of-facade-object that can use both APIs (3rd party and yours)

Comment: would mimicking the api potentially lead to confusing the QA from thinking an api is responding when in fact its returning fake data? In other words, how does QA know its "mock time"

Comment: @joey I'd hope that QA would have the ability to actively choose when to use the mocks over the real test API.

Comment: It’s getting more confusing, please add more details, maybe a visual

Comment: @vasily.sib That will be a great solution, I can save dummy XMLs on S3 and can switch the mode between actual supplier and dummy supplier. I can actually update the XMLs timely on S3 with latest content from supplier.

Comment: @joey If supplier is down QA team will have ability to turn on dummy supplier to test. The supplier data is not that frequently updated. It will help QA team at least to ensure new code/features are not breaking without third party API dependency.

Comment: Use API Simulations "...to mimic third party API". You can write your own tool or use one of the tools out there. (disclaimer: I'm involved with one such tool)